# Format dates in red when variable date threshold is passed

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I am trying to get past due dates to show red.

I can’t use conditional formatting because the “past due date” is dependent on another column.

In column C, level_of_care, are list of Supportive or Connective. They have different dates due. In column D, f2f date and column E, hv_date.

Column D is f2f_date and if the dates are overdue I need them to:

- If Connective: f2f to show red if older than 90 days.
- If Supportive: f2f to show red if older than 30 days.

In column E is hv_date and if the dates are over due I need them to:

- If Connective: hv to show red if older than 1 year.
- If Supportive: hv to show red if older than 90 days.

Did you get all that? Two columns of dates to show red when past due- but the past due dates are dependent on supportive or connective- I cannot simply put a conditional formatting on there- they due dates are different depending on the level of care.

Comment: This is pretty confusing as written but if its possible to write a condition that evaluates to `TRUE` then you can use conditional formatting.

Comment: @bugdrown, I thought so too at first, but it was more of a matter of formatting than wording. As soon as I replaced the single linebreaks with double linebreaks, it suddenly became much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up some hidden calculated columns to evaluate the overdue days based on the conditions you require. Then use the result in these columns to apply your conditional formatting to the actual column being output.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional formatting formulas are pretty powerful and you can certainly use them in that case (no need for VBA).

For instance, with this data:

| level_of_care | f2f_date | hv_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Connective | 2023-06-08 | 2022-01-21 |
| Connective | 2023-04-17 | 2023-05-10 |
| Supportive | 2023-03-30 | 2023-04-11 |
| Supportive | 2023-03-28 | 2023-02-27 |

[image]

You can use the following conditional formatting formula for column D and it will return `TRUE` only when the variable threshold is passed:

`=IF(D2<TODAY()-IF(C2="Connective",90,30),TRUE,FALSE)`

For column E, it would be something like this:

`=IF(E2<TODAY()-IF(C2="Connective",365,90),TRUE,FALSE)`

After selecting the column, when you add the conditional formatting, use the "New Rule" option :

[image]

This will allow you to select the fomula option:

[image]

And you should get something like this in the end:

[image]

Comment: For this to work, it needs to look more like:
f2f
=IF(E2<TODAY()-IF(C2="Connective",90),-IF(C2="Supportive",30),TRUE,FALSE)

hv
=IF(F2<TODAY()-IF(C2="Connective",365),-IF(C2="Supportive",90),TRUE,FALSE)    

I get the error: You've entered too many arguments for this function. This is why I don't think I can use conditional formatting.

Comment: @CS_A - Both approaches work, but if you have more than 2 options for the lelvel of care, I can see how your approach is more flexible. Regarding the error in your formula, you have an excess comma here `...,-IF(C2="Supportive"...` for instance.

Comment: @CS_A - Were you able to make it work?

Comment: =IF($C1="Connective", TODAY()-$E1<90)=AND($C1="Supportive", TODAY()-$E1<30)
This is the working formula! Thank you!